# Do Fuerte packages using Eigen need to depend on common_rosdeps?

Tags: eigen, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a bit confused about this. The [Eigen wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/eigen) indicates that, for Fuerte, a package's manifest.xml needs to have

```
  <depend package="common_rosdeps" />
  <rosdep name="eigen" />
```

.. but the [common_rosdeps wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/common_rosdeps) says that this "stack/package" (which is it?) is "deprecated" and "no longer necessary".

I've tried commenting out both lines above and my code still seems to build happily so maybe this only matters in a rosinstall situation (which I tend not to do). But at any rate the information on the Eigen wiki page is still a bit confusing since it recommends depending on a deprecated package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33311/do-fuerte-packages-using-eigen-need-to-depend-on-common_rosdeps?/) by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2264 on 2012-05-04

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Eigen is now an external library so if you use Eigen, make sure your CMakeLists.txt has:

```
find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Eigen_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

so your code will compile. You don't need to add common_rosdeps anymore for Fuerte, you are correct, it is depreciated.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2012-05-06**:
Thanks. I tweaked the Eigen wiki page to hopefully make it clearer.